# Linear algebra , Kernel, range , dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:

$dim(V)=n$ and $dim(W)=m$ , $n>m$ , (without using rank nullity theorem), let $T:V {\rightarrow} W$ is a linear transformation. Prove that there is a non zero $v$ in $V$ such that $T(v)=0_w$.

My answer:

Since $T$ is linear transformation we can say : for every $v\in V$ , there is $w\in W$ such that $T(v)=w$ ( is this correct ? ). let $B_v= (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ and$ B_w=(w_1,\ldots,w_m)$
then $T(cv_1+\cdots+c_nv_n)=c_1w_1+\cdots+c_nw_n$ By using linear transformation definition we get to $T(c_{m+1}v_{m+1}+\cdots+c_nv_n)=c_{m+1}w_{m+1}+\cdots+c_nw_n$. Then I am stuck and confused ! can someone please explain some of the basics here

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{ e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n \}$ be a basis of $V$. We know that $\{ f(e_1), f(e_2), \dots, f(e_n) \}$ spans $f(V)$, the image of $V$ by $f$.

Since the dimension of the image is less or equal than $m$, at most m vectors of  $\{ f(e_1), f(e_2) \dots, f(e_n) \}$ are linearly independent. Therefore, one of the vectors, say $f(e_n)$ can we written as a linear combination of the rest:
$$ f(e_n) = a_1 f(e_1) + a_2 f(e_2) + \dots + a_{n-1} f(e_{n-1}) $$

Then by the linearity of $f$
$$ f(e_n - a_1 e_1 - \dots - a_{n-1} e_{n-1}) = 0 $$